# Probleme mit der Kommasetzung bei Einschüben

Tags: subordinate-clause, comma, apposition

Folgendes Beispiel:

> Im Folgenden werden einige, für diese Arbeit essenzielle, Termini erläutert.

Mir ist nun aufgefallen, dass der Satz auch ohne die Kommata vollständigen Sinn ergibt:

> Im Folgenden werden einige für diese Arbeit essenzielle Termini erläutert.

Allerdings sollte der erste Satz auch grammatikalisch richtig sein, da der Hauptsatz alleine grammatikalisch vollständig ist:

> Im Folgenden werden einige Termini erläutert.

Da ich schon immer etwas Probleme mit der korrekten Kommasetzung hatte, wollte ich hier nur fragen, ob ich richtig liege und beide Varianten grammatikalisch korrekt sind.

Oder ist das überhaupt gar kein Einschub und die ganze Frage schwachsinnig?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was du uns vorlegst, ist eine **eingeschobene Adjektivgruppe**, die durch Satzzeichen abgetrennt werden kann, aber nicht muss. Die Kommas sind also optional und könnten außerdem durch (freilich ebenso optionale) Gedankenstriche bzw. Klammern ersetzt werden.

> - Im Folgenden werden einige – **für diese Arbeit essenzielle** – Termini
>     erläutert.
> - Im Folgenden werden einige (**für diese Arbeit essenzielle**) Termini erläutert.

Quelle: [Duden-Regel D 114](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K114)

Es gibt allerdings auch eingeschobene Adjektivgruppen, die zwingend durch Satzzeichen abzutrennen sind, z. B. wenn sie mit einem hinweisenden Wort oder einer Wortgruppe angekündigt werden:

> Nur so, **bleich und dürr**, ist mir mein Großvater in Erinnerung geblieben.

Quelle: [Duden-Regel D 115](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K115)

Comment: Wobei mir bei der Variante ganz ohne Satzzeichen schon etwas fehlt, was von meinem Sprachgefühl da hin gehört.